# Index of root \

Tags: apache

I have a webserver running on port 80 on CentOS7 like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.server.nl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my.server.nl/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/my.server.nl/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/my.server.nl/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine. The VirtualHost is set in a directory called `sites-available` and linked to from `sites-enabled`, all good.
Now I copy/paste the VirtualHost and change the port, I expect to run the same site on a different port.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName my.server.nl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my.server.nl/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/my.server.nl/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/my.server.nl/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I browser to the copy of the working site on the other port, all I see is an empty page with `Index of /`
In fact, no matter what I use as DocumentRoot, this is always the result of the new VirtualHost.

How can this be?

- restarted the service (sudo systemctl restart httpd)
- checked all permissons
- firewall is ok
- exact copy, 100% the same documents
- added port to httpd.conf, or it will deny any access (why?!)

Comment: Which version is this? In 2.2 you need this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 12 2017 21:03:28

Comment: Maybe it would worth trying what happens if you break the working block. Just to double check whether that one is really the working. (with 2.4.6 that namevirtualhost is not needed AFAIK.)

Comment: Thanks, but I have reinstalled the server from the ground up and now it's working with the same code.